# Custom QWidget in different file than main function

Tags: c++, qt

I have a little question about Qt custom Widgets.

Both in http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.3/tutorial-t4.html and http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.3/tutorial-t8.html, the custom window declaration is made in the *main.cpp* file, where the *qApp* pointer is accesible(in the second link, more widgets are declared in their own files).

Couldn't the window be done in another different file and have the *qApp* pointer passed to it?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the main windows can be created in another file. All you need in the main is to create the `QApplication` and show something that you include. And then start the event loop.

You don't have to pass `qApp` pointer anywhere. It is a global reference to the only single application that can be running. Just access it in any other file by including `QApplication`.

Also be advised, those tutorials are for Qt 4.3 which is old (unless you are bound to use that version right now). You can find [tutorials for Qt 4.8 here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tutorials.html)

Comment: Hi!! Thanks for your answer and sorry for my late reply!! :)